# calling write and read function in smart contract using python web3?

Tags: web3js, dapps, web3.py, python

I have a claim smart contract and I want to call the function to python.
This is the function

```
struct ClaimList{
        uint256 claimCounts;
        uint256 amount;
        address agentAddress;
        string icon;
        string tokenName;
        string remarks;
        IERC20 token;
        bool is_Claimed;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => ClaimList)) public claimList;
    mapping(address => uint256[])  mcounts;

function setClaimables (
        uint256 [] memory amount,
        address [] memory agentAddress,
        string [] memory icons,
        string [] memory tokenNames,
        string [] memory remarks,
        IERC20 [] memory token
    ) external onlyAdmin {

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < agentAddress.length; i++) {
            ClaimList storage listClaim = claimList[counter][agentAddress[i]];

            listClaim.claimCounts = counter;
            listClaim.amount = amount[i];
            listClaim.agentAddress = agentAddress[i];
            listClaim.icon = icons[i];
            listClaim.tokenName = tokenNames[i];
            listClaim.remarks = remarks[i];
            listClaim.token = token[i];
            listClaim.is_Claimed = false;

            mcounts[agentAddress[i]].push(counter);
            counter += 1;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

When you use `web3.py` to interact with smart contracts, you can divide the script into three parts:

- Connect to the network.
- Initialize the smart contract & account to sign the transactions from.
- Call functions and transactions.

> The following example calls functions from an ERC20 smart contract, but you can adapt it to your contract by using your contract's ABI and address.

### Connect to the network

I always use this syntax to connect my scripts to a network, you can also use an environment variable, but I usually keep it simple for test scripts.

```py
from web3 import Web3

# Initialize endpoint URL
node_url = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL"

# Create the node connection
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url))
```

I usually add an if statement to give a message on the console to verify if the connection is successful (non-required but excellent for the user).

```py
# Verify if the connection is successful
if web3.isConnected():
    print("-" * 50)
    print("Connection Successful")
    print("-" * 50)
else:
    print("Connection Failed")
```

### Initialize smart contract and account

To call functions from a smart contract, we need to specify its address and ABI first.

```py
# Initialize the address calling the functions/signing transactions
caller = "YOUR_ADDRESS"
private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY"  # To sign the transaction

# Initialize address nonce
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(caller)

# Initialize contract ABI and address
abi = '[{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"balanceLeft","type":"uint256"}],"name":"balance","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"destroy","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}'

contract_address = "CONTRACT_ADDRESS"

# Create smart contract instance
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)
```

### Call functions and transactions

Now we can start calling functions; we can do it two ways:

- Build a transaction to call a function that modifies the state of the network.
- `.call` in case the function is only reading from the blockchain (if it's a `view` or `pure` function).

#### Call a function that modifies the state

For this, we need to build a transaction to send.

The following example calls a function with no parameters named `testFunc()`, but you can put your `setClaimables()` function in it and add the parameters.

```py
# initialize the chain id, we need it to build the transaction for replay protection
Chain_id = web3.eth.chain_id

# Call your function
call_function = contract.functions.testFunc().buildTransaction({"chainId": Chain_id, "from": caller, "nonce": nonce})

# Sign transaction
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(call_function, private_key=private_key)

# Send transaction
send_tx = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

# Wait for transaction receipt
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_tx)
# print(tx_receipt) # Optional
```

#### Call a pure or view function

Then if you want to call a function that only reads from the network (`view` or `pure`), you only need to "call" it since it will not make an actual transaction.

For example the `totalSupply()` function from an ERC20 token contract.

```py
totalSupply = contract.functions.totalSupply().call()  # read the coin total supply - call means we are reading from the blockchain
print(totalSupply)
```

You can check the [Ethereum API reference page](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/ethereum-api-reference) on the Chainstack docs to see more `web3.py` code examples!

I hope this helps you!